# Gamma Spectrum: What is causing this behavior?

Tags: radiation, gamma-rays

In my radiation detection lab we're identifying a unknown source, based on the gamma spectrum it's an activated gold foil. You can clearly see 4 peaks: 411.78 keV (Au-198), 675.93 keV (Au-198), 823.51 (Mo-99), and 1087.86 keV (Au-198). Spectrum should be here: [image: Gamma spectrum from unknown source. Likely activated Au foil]The Mo-99 peaks looks strange to me though. I'm unsure what's causing that weird hump before the peak. Does anyone know what causes this and/or can direct me on where to read up on it?

Thanks

Comment: How is the "gold foil" excited? By electron bombardment?

Comment: I'm not sure; it was prepared in our campus reactor by another class. I'm guessing they passed a Au-197 foil through some neutron flux in the reactor. That should produce Au-198.

Comment: That shoulder looks vaguely like a Compton scattering peak, but I can't suss out why you would see it on only one peak. From the appearance of the data I assume this is from a Ge-detector and they rarely show such structures.

Comment: Worth while question: is the vertical axis on a linear, log or square-root scale?

Comment: It was from an Ortec HPGe detector using the GammaVision software package. Y scale is Log.

Comment: Uhg. And you're using Ortec's software, too, aren't you? While there is nothing actually *wrong* with the data recording Ortec's display software does a rotten job of dealing with calibration drift and issues that these detectors *are* subject to.

Comment: In any case, that may just be the detection tail of the peak. I'm not sure why it would be so much more prominent on that line, though.

Answer (score 2):

The peak at 823.51 is two 411.78 keV photon being detected as a single photon. The odd peak structure is due to a "full" x-ray plus another partially scattered x-ray being as a sum peak.